# how to create a route in Sinatra to return a range of ids?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, range

Can I pass more than one value to the same parameter, e.g.

`get '/:id/:id'` or `get /1/100`

and then return the range from one id to the other?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
get '/:start/:finish' do
  params[:start].to_i..params[:finish].to_i
end
```

Comment: of course, if you want to show range on the page, you have to add to_s at the end of this expression or even to_a.to_s :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to access the range this way. But I'm still struggling with my goal, which is to return data from the range of records. 

For example, this doesn't work:   

`get '/:start/:finish' do  
  (params[:start]..params[:finish]).each do |p|  
    p = Photo.get params[:id]  
    json 'id' => @photo.id, 'photo' => @photo.image.to_s  
  end  
end`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In such case, what are params[:id] referenced? Block variable 'p' is equal to id integer consequentially, from 'start' to 'finish'. You should this variable for retrieving you data, ...each do |id| Photo.get(id) .... (e.g. if you use DataMapper)